# Undertow never sends HTTP/2 trailers for plain servlet?

Tags: wildfly, undertow

I tried to let an extremely simple servlet send HTTP/2 trailers in response. I succeeded doing so by running my servlet on Glassfish 5.0 or Tomcat 9.0.10. I can clearly see the trailers received by the HTTP/2 client [nghttp](https://github.com/http2/http2-spec/wiki/Tools).

However, when I try Undertow 2.0.10.Final (which claimed to support servlet 4.0 and HTTP/2), the servlet only sends the payload but never sends trailers. I tried Spring Boot + Undertow as well as standalone Wildfly, and non of them sends trailers.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/hellotrailer"})
public class HelloTrailer extends HttpServlet {
  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws IOException {
    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.setHeader("trailers", "hello");

    Map<String, String> trailers = new HashMap<>();
    trailers.put("hello", "world");
    resp.setTrailerFields(() -> trailers);
    resp.getWriter().write("payload");
  }
}
```

**Edit**: The following is the details of the client output when sending request to `Wildfly 13.0.0.Final` server with `--server-config=standalone-ee8.xml` or `wildfly-14.0.0.Beta1` server, or `Undertow 9.0.11` with spring boot.

```
nghttp "https://127.0.0.1:8443/servlettest-1.0-SNAPSHOT/hellotrailer" -v -H ":method:GET"
[  0.003] Connected
[WARNING] Certificate verification failed: Hostname mismatch
The negotiated protocol: h2
[  0.025] send SETTINGS frame <length=12, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
          (niv=2)
          [SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS(0x03):100]
          [SETTINGS_INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE(0x04):65535]
[  0.025] send PRIORITY frame <length=5, flags=0x00, stream_id=3>
          (dep_stream_id=0, weight=201, exclusive=0)
[  0.025] send PRIORITY frame <length=5, flags=0x00, stream_id=5>
          (dep_stream_id=0, weight=101, exclusive=0)
[  0.025] send PRIORITY frame <length=5, flags=0x00, stream_id=7>
          (dep_stream_id=0, weight=1, exclusive=0)
[  0.025] send PRIORITY frame <length=5, flags=0x00, stream_id=9>
          (dep_stream_id=7, weight=1, exclusive=0)
[  0.025] send PRIORITY frame <length=5, flags=0x00, stream_id=11>
          (dep_stream_id=3, weight=1, exclusive=0)
[  0.025] send HEADERS frame <length=67, flags=0x25, stream_id=13>
          ; END_STREAM | END_HEADERS | PRIORITY
          (padlen=0, dep_stream_id=11, weight=16, exclusive=0)
          ; Open new stream
          :method: GET
          :path: /servlettest-1.0-SNAPSHOT/hellotrailer
          :scheme: https
          :authority: 127.0.0.1:8443
          accept: */*
          accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
          user-agent: nghttp2/1.31.1
[  0.026] recv SETTINGS frame <length=24, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
          (niv=4)
          [SETTINGS_HEADER_TABLE_SIZE(0x01):4096]
          [SETTINGS_MAX_FRAME_SIZE(0x05):16384]
          [SETTINGS_INITIAL_WINDOW_SIZE(0x04):65535]
          [SETTINGS_MAX_HEADER_LIST_SIZE(0x06):1048576]
[  0.026] send SETTINGS frame <length=0, flags=0x01, stream_id=0>
          ; ACK
          (niv=0)
[  0.026] recv SETTINGS frame <length=0, flags=0x01, stream_id=0>
          ; ACK
          (niv=0)
[  0.061] recv (stream_id=13) :status: 200
[  0.061] recv (stream_id=13) trailers: hello
[  0.061] recv (stream_id=13) content-type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
[  0.061] recv (stream_id=13, sensitive) content-length: 7
[  0.061] recv (stream_id=13, sensitive) date: Fri, 03 Aug 2018 22:56:33 GMT
[  0.061] recv HEADERS frame <length=70, flags=0x04, stream_id=13>
          ; END_HEADERS
          (padlen=0)
          ; First response header
payload[  0.061] recv DATA frame <length=7, flags=0x01, stream_id=13>
          ; END_STREAM
[  0.061] send GOAWAY frame <length=8, flags=0x00, stream_id=0>
          (last_stream_id=0, error_code=NO_ERROR(0x00), opaque_data(0)=[])
```

As you can see only headers and payload were recevied, no trailers. The trailers can be observed if sending the same request to `Glassfish 5.0`, `Tomcat 9.0.10`, `Jetty 10.0-SNAPSHOT` servers:

```
payload[  0.143] recv DATA frame <length=7, flags=0x00, stream_id=13>
[  0.143] recv (stream_id=13) hello: world
[  0.143] recv HEADERS frame <length=11, flags=0x05, stream_id=13>
          ; END_STREAM | END_HEADERS
          (padlen=0)
```

**Update: Problem Resolved**

This was verified as undertow issue https://issues.jboss.org/projects/UNDERTOW/issues/UNDERTOW-1389
and was fixed in undertow v 2.0.12.Final

Comment: Did you enable http2? It requests extra configuration and ssl certificate to be enabled.

Comment: @ctomc yes, as you can see the output of nghttp command that I Edited in the question, it is doing HTTP/2 request with TLS. I ran Wildfly 13.0.0.Final server with ./standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-ee8.xml, or wildfly-14.0.0.Beta1 server with ./standalone, or Undertow with spring boot configuring http2 and ssl following https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-http2 and https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-ssl. What extra configuration do I need?